# c++11 wrappers for OpenGL calls

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl

Most of the OpenGL API calls do not return a value. With C++11 perfect forwarding, it would be easy to write an error-checking wrapper function template and variadic macro such as this:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
void call(
    const char *text,
    int line,
    const char *file,
    F && f, Args &&... args
    )
{
    std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto err = glGetError();
    if (err != 0) _throw_error(text, err, line, file);
}

#define GL(fn, ...) call(#fn, __LINE__, __FILE__, gl##fn, __VA_ARGS__)
```

This works and allows calls to be written like this:

```cpp
GL(Viewport, 0, 0, 1920, 1080);
```

However, some OpenGL functions do return a value, making it necessary for the wrapper function to store the return value in a temporary variable before checking for errors. The wrapper function template for calls with return values could be written like this:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
auto call(
    const char *text,
    int line,
    const char *file,
    F && f, Args &&... args
    )
{
    auto && res = std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto err = glGetError();
    if (err != 0) _throw_error(text, err, line, file);
    return res;
}
```

(The same macro can be used to call this form.)

The problem is that it is not possible to define *both* of the above function templates, because for all API calls with `void` return type, both templates will match, leading to an "ambiguous call to overloaded function" error (Visual C++).

It would be possible, of course, to define separate macros for the two forms, but that would not be elegant. `GL` is the natural, obvious and correct choice for the name of the wrapper macro, and any additional macro (such as `GLR`) would appear ugly and be difficult to remember.

Comment: `This is going to be a self-answered question` Then answer it *while* you ask it. Don't ask it, then spend minutes compiling the answer. That's why there's an "answer" checkbox at the bottom of the Ask a Question page.

Comment: Also, you're using `glGetError` wrong. It can return multiple errors. And glIntercept is much better at this anyway.

Comment: I missed that checkbox. But that's not worth a downvote or a vote to close. I honestly didn't know about multiple error flags though, and I admit I'm not sure how to handle this. In my experience though, calling glGetError() after each call has always done the job, except for `glEnd()` which is deprecated anyway.

Comment: You know that there are [debug contexts](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Debug_Output) in modern OpenGL?

Comment: @BDL: I actually didn't. I just looked it up, and it sounds like I'm gonna need that sometime. However the purpose here is plain error-checking.

Answer (score 4):

Especially in a release build, you do not want to call `glGetError` after every single call. It will not be good for performance, and `glGetError` doesn't return descriptive errors anyway (`GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is used for a lot of things).

Instead, for debugging, create a [debug context](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Debug_Output) and register a callback using [`glDebugMessageCallback​`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDebugMessageCallback) that prints out the error messages. This is a relatively new OpenGL feature, but provides much better messages in my experience.

```
void debug_callback(GLenum source​, GLenum type​, GLuint id​,
    GLenum severity​, GLsizei length​, const GLchar* message​, const void* userParam) {
    printf("%s", message);
}
glDebugMessageCallback​(&debug_callback​, nullptr​);
```

Comment: Thanks @Colonel! I'm going to add this to my toolbox. Regarding performance, I haven't shown this in my posts, but the release build defines the macro `GL` so that it just calls the function directly, without any checking at all.

Comment: is the debug callback called before the OpenGL call returns? Can this be relied on?

Comment: @JPNotADragon The callback function may be called asynchronously, unless you call `glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS)`

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the above problem is not very difficult, however I was surprised to find that Visual C++ would not accept (meaning that it choked with an internal compiler error) the solution that I had worked out and verified using [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com), which uses gcc.

What is needed of course is [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), and C++11 supports that with the very handy [`std::enable_if<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). The solution that worked with gcc, but didn't with Visual Studio 2015, was this:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename ...Args,
    typename R = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>>::value, std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>>>
>
R call(const char *text, int line, const char *file, F && f, Args &&...args)
{...}
```

(and similar for void functions, with `std:is_void<...>::value` instead).

After some searching, I came up with the following that does compile:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
auto call(
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>>::value, const char> *text,
    int line,
    const char *file,
    F && f, Args &&... args
    )
{
    auto && res = std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto err = glGetError();
    if (err != 0) _throw_error(text, err, line, file);
    return res;
}
```

and

```cpp
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
void call(
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>>::value, const char> *text,
    int line,
    const char *file,
    F && f, Args &&... args
    )
{
    std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto err = glGetError();
    if (err != 0) _throw_error(text, err, line, file);
}
```

The only remarkable thing about this solution is the way it makes use of SFINAE. `std::enable_if_t<>` not only serves to eliminate the unwanted specialization, but at the same time declares the type of the `text` parameter passed in by the macro. So, instead of doing SFINAE via an extra, unused parameter with a default value (which I tried but for some reason also lead to an "internal compiler error" under Visual Studio), I just used it on one of the three extra parameters that I needed anyway.